# how to get file size under 100 megabytes

Tags: c#, file, size

I created a function to scan a directory to get certain files, how can I run the scan command after finding the appropriate file size I want?
for example, I want to delete a file in a directory, but before deleting the file I want to get or know whether the file size is under 100 megabytes or not, if the file size is above 100 megabytes, it will ignore the command.

I tried to look for the basic, but how do I get files under 100 megabytes?

```
if (new FileInfo (file) .Length <= 12345)
{
string file = "myfile";
File.Delete(file)

}
```

Comment: replace `12345` with `100 * 1024 * 1024` because `Length` is the size in `Bytes`

Comment: Or 100 * 1000 * 1000 or 100 * 1024 * 1000 according to your preferred definition of [megabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte). Also if you want files UNDER 100megabytes change the condition to check for less than, rather than less than or equal. You shouldn't need to set the file name inside the if statement either as you have already used it when checking the length

Comment: @PaulF filesystem context `1024` and networking context `1000` there is no preferred way

Comment: @fubo: base 10 variant : _"This definition is used in networking contexts and most storage media, particularly hard drives, ....."_. Base 2 variant : _"is the definition used by Microsoft Windows in reference to computer memory, such as RAM"_. Mixed : _"is the definition used to describe the formatted capacity of the 1.44 MB 3.5-inch HD floppy disk,"_ I assume, but cannot be 100% sure, OP is not using a floppy disk. I also stated "your" preferred way - as there is no overall preferred way.

Comment: @PaulF I know, that's just an example

Comment: @NurohmanAR: your code is pretty much correct  (beyond using the right value and setting another filename inside the if statement) - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: just want to get the file size under 100 megabytes, nothing else.
thankyou

Comment: @NurohmanAR Doesn't your code already do that (ajusting the values, of course)? It only enters the `if`  if the file is bellow the specified size

Comment: At first I didn't know how to write 100 megabytes of format into the code

Comment: @NurohmanAR: so have we answered you question? You may need to read the link I gave & make up your mind on what definition of "megabyte" to use as there is variation on what the term means. Rather than a calculation as fubo & I have shown you can write the value itself 104857600 or 100000000 or 102400000

Comment: yes, already answered. thankyou @PaulF.